# Getting ‘_internal_get_deleter’ missing error in Boost library

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, boost-thread

I successfully build `boost_1_45_0` using source code in `Ubuntu` but when i am using `BOOST` to build another package:

```
Scanning dependencies of target GraphMolWrap
```

[ 98%] Building CXX object

```
Code/JavaWrappers/gmwrapper/CMakeFiles/GraphMolWrap.dir/GraphMolJavaJAVA_wrap.cxx.o
/opt/RDKit/build/Code/JavaWrappers/gmwrapper/GraphMolJavaJAVA_wrap.cxx: In function ‘jlong     
Java_org_RDKit_RDKFuncsJNI_Shared_1Int_1Array_1_1internal_1get_1deleter(JNIEnv*, jclass,   
jlong, 

jobject, jlong)’:
/opt/RDKit/build/Code/JavaWrappers/gmwrapper/GraphMolJavaJAVA_wrap.cxx:134276:68: error:     
‘const   class boost::shared_array<int>’ has no member named ‘_internal_get_deleter’

/opt/RDKit/build/Code/JavaWrappers/gmwrapper/GraphMolJavaJAVA_wrap.cxx: In function ‘jlong    
Java_org_RDKit_RDKFuncsJNI_Shared_1Double_1Array_1_1internal_1get_1deleter(JNIEnv*, jclass,   
jlon g, jobject, jlong)’:

/opt/RDKit/build/Code/JavaWrappers/gmwrapper/GraphMolJavaJAVA_wrap.cxx:134936:71: error:   
‘const class boost::shared_array<double>’ has no member named ‘_internal_get_deleter’

 make[2]: ***   
 [Code/JavaWrappers/gmwrapper/CMakeFiles/GraphMolWrap.dir/GraphMolJavaJAVA_wrap.cxx.o] Error     
 1

 make[1]: *** [Code/JavaWrappers/gmwrapper/CMakeFiles/GraphMolWrap.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**HIGHLIGHTING Error:**  `const class boost::shared_array<double>’ has no member named ‘_internal_get_deleter’`

Comment: I suspect you're pulling in two different versions of boost, based on your search path. One is likely in `/usr/include/boost`, the other somewhere else (possibly in /opt)

Comment: Could also be that the code (ab)used internal library details that have been removed/changed in the version of the library currently used